Positioning of datasummary_skim() output in pdf file when knitting rmarkdown file
I'm writing to you to ask for help. More specifically, I am writing a paper as an rmarkdown file, which I can knit to pdf.Here is the R code of one of the chunks:

{r results='asis'}
datasummary_skim(data_df) |>
kable_styling(font_size = 8, full_width = FALSE)

The problem is that the output of this code (namely a table) is displayed in the pdf file at the beginning of the page, rather than in its original positioning.
May you help me solve this issue? I've been searching a lot for any possible solution, but I didn't manage to find one.
Thanks in advance!
As mentioned upon, I am expecting this table to be shown in the right position even in the pdf file. Instead, it's displayed at the beginning.

In versions >2.0.0 of modelsummary, the default table-drawing package is no longer kableExtra, but rather tintyable.
You can find details in the "Placement" section of the PDF tutorial (not the HTML one) at this website: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/tinytable/
Your code should look similar to this:
library(modelsummary)
library(tinytable)
datasummary_skim(data_df) |> 
  theme_tt("placement", latex_float = "H") |>)

Again, this requires version 2.0.0 of modelsummary
